# Regex for name not containing adjacent periods (.), hyphens (-), or underscores (_)

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I've been working on a regex for a name with the following criteria:

1. Contain only ASCII letters (`a-z`, `A-Z`), numbers (`0-9`), periods (`.`), underscores (`_`), or dashes (`-`)
2. Start with a letter or number, and end with a letter or number
3. Be between 3 and 128 characters
4. Have no adjacent periods, underscores or dashes. Names like `my-_namespace`
   and `my--namespace` are invalid.

So far, I've come up with the following pattern:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9](?!.*--)[a-zA-Z0-9._-]{1,126}[A-Za-z0-9]$
```

This works for adjacent hyphens. How do I incorporate functionality for no adjacent hyphens, underscores and dots?

Comment: Use `^(?=.{3,128}$)[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[._-][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$`

Comment: Try `^(?!.*[._-]{2})[^\W_][\w.-]{1,126}[^\W_]$`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew. Please post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could could go overboard with the lookaheads and non-capturing groups:

1. Check the length of the whole string with a positive lookahead.
2. Check for non-repeated separators with a negative lookahead.

```
^(?=.{3,128})[0-9A-Za-z](?:[0-9A-Za-z]|(?:[-_\.](?![-_\.])))+[0-9A-Za-z]$
       ^           ^            ^            ^       ^            ^
       |           |            |            |       |            |
     Length     Starts      Either a       Or a     but          Ends
     check       with        letter      sepatator  not          with
                letter                            followed      letter
                                                 by another
                                                 separator
```

Comment: Good answer but you forgot to add `.` in `[-_\]` and had an extra group that I removed them. Also `^` and `$` anchors were missing.

Comment: @revo. In future, restrict yourself to leaving a comment before modifying someone else's code. The "extra" group you removed is a negative lookahead.

Comment: The extra group I removed is a non-capturing group around `[-_\.](?![-_\.])`. Sorry I took back my vote.

Comment: @revo. I misread the edits. Does the `|` symbol grab as much as it can or as little? I always thought it was the latter, but was never sure enough to omit the parens.

Answer (score 1):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]([0-9A-Za-z]|[\._-](?![\._-])){1,126}[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

This part avoids the repeated chars `[\._-](?![\._-])`

So you end up with an alternation between chars, numbers and single dots, single underscores and single dashes

Answer (score 1):

One way is to put negative lookahead that prohibits such combinations in the beginning of regex.

```
^(?!.*[\._-]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\._-]{1,126}[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/SGoOe3Fuk4k0pdyF)

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the same (?!.*--) negative lookahead with underscores and dots? Something like this:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9](?!.*--)(?!.*\.\.)(?!.*__)[a-zA-Z0-9._-]{1,126}[A-Za-z0-9]$
```